# Mcculloch and Pitts Neurons: Is there errata in this article?

Tags: neural-networks, perceptron, theory

The paper A LOGICAL CALCULUS OF THE IDEAS IMMANENT IN NERVOUS ACTIVITY has the following description of neurons, which I question if there is errata or perhaps I need more information to understand this.

Looking at the picture below (b) is described as an OR gate.  I'm confused because with either threshold being met on the $N_1$ or $N_2$ neuron, with thresholds 1 and 2, there are not enough inputs to reach the threshold of 3 for $N_3$.  So how is this an OR gate?

(c) makes sense because the sum of the input to $N_3$ is 3 when both $N_1$ and $N_2$ are at their thresholds.

Any guidance appreciated.

[image: Neurons]
[image: Descriptions]

Comment: Generally speaking "errata" in English refers to a section of text giving corrections for errors in another piece of writing. You seem to be using the word like it means "errors", which in English it doesn't.

Comment: @Joffan I didn't know that.  Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, the document that fixes a single error is an erratum. An errata fixes several of them.

Comment: Last but not least, in error correction terminology, errata collectively denote the errors (alterations of the message at unknown places) and erasures (alterations at known places). :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you know the etymology of Erratum and Errata in Latin?  Or just the dictionary definition?  Thanks

Comment: @Nick: errata is the plural form of erratum. In case I am wrong, errare humanum est.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the article mentioned, the figures each have a threshold of 2 for each neuron.  Therefore there is no errata.

Comment: Figure (b) has triangles labeled 1, 2 and 3.  I'm assuming these are the dendrite or soma.  Are the numbers thresholds or are they dendrite/soma identifiers?  Figure (b) also has lines that branch out into one or more black circles which should be the axon.  Does the number of branched out black circles which meet the next triangle represent the signal strength?  I'm assuming there is a threshold that must be met.

Comment: The notes at the bottom of the diagram tell you that these numbers are just labels: "The neuron $c_i$ is marked with the numeral $i$ upon the body of the cell"

Comment: Looking at these closer, it appears the threshold input value of the dendrite/soma is 2 black circles from the axon.  If the 2 threshold is met then the input neuron, will fire its output axon at time t + 1.  Does this agree with you?

Comment: Yes, that seems to make sense; the (0/1) state is transmitted at double strength.

Comment: I was a bit puzzled by the $.\!\lor .$ notation but I think it just indicates the larger scope of that $\lor$ instead of using brackets, in conjunction with using $:\equiv:$ instead of $.\!\equiv.$

Comment: .V. is notation for multiple levels of parenthesis, which if in original notation would be hard to read.  The period algorithm on what periods to match are taken from Bertrand Russel's Principia Mathematica and originally from G. Peano's publications on arithmetic.  Church uses them partially in the Lambda Calculus.  If you find the Principia Mathematica PDF online, Russel explains in English (Peano is Italian) how to read the periods in the first few chapters of his book.  They basically match up, unless the operation is the product, which a single unmatched dot.

Comment: @Joffan here you go on the period notation, hope this helps. https://ibb.co/3B15p3f